# Importing Angular components to a module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've recently started playing with angular 2, and found it really great. However I found myself doing repetitive things like importing all kind of components everywhere.

I have the following code:

```
/************** my.module.ts **************/
import { MyRoutingModule } from './my-routes.module';

// these imports are done twice
import { FirstComponent } from 'components/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from 'components/second.component';
import { ThirdComponent } from 'components/third.component';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [ MyRoutingModule ],
    declarations: [
        FirstComponent, SecondComponent, ThirdComponent 
    ]
})
export class MyModule { }


/************** my-routes.module.ts **************/
import { FirstComponent } from 'components/first.component';
import { SecondComponent } from 'components/second.component';
import { ThirdComponent } from 'components/third.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent },
    { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent },
    { path: 'third', component: ThirdComponent },
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

I have a considerable number of components that need to be imported twice, in the routing module and module itself, the former is for the declarations entry and the later for rounting purposes.

I know I can have a shared module that exports all my common components and then import that module where I need it, that's fine. I understand that approach is for avoiding reimporting the same components everywhere, but for the sake of routing I need the imports to be done in the same file so the component classes can be recognized and used.

Is a better way for doing this?